1970 thriller movie set in a large high-rise apartment in America
As a young child (well about 10/11) I remember watching a thriller movie which was repeated several times in my youth, where a woman who lived in a high-rise apartment was being stalked by someone from another high-rise apartment using a telescope, I think.  
If memory serves me well, the stalker was committing murders and this woman knew she was a target, whether by receiving phone calls or letters, I cant quite remember. I recall near the end the stalker arriving in her apartment and her hiding behind the curtains? The apartment had huge ceiling to floor windows too.
Don't think there was anyone famous in it.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

It can be Someone's Watching Me!

A woman named Leigh Michaels moves to Los Angeles, and finds a job directing live television. An older man sees her on the balcony of her new apartment, through a telescope. He enters her apartment when she's out, and begins to terrorize her with phone calls and strange gifts from a fictional company, "Excursions Unlimited".
Michaels reports the harassment to the police, but because no threat has been expressed, they take no action. The gifts include a telescope, but Michaels does not understand she is being watched until the second half of the film. With the help of co-worker Sophie and boyfriend Paul Winkless, she attempts to take action against the voyeur.

She did get the call, as clear from trailer bellow:



